# Spacy Natural Language Processing Pickle file issue

Tags: nlp, pickle, spacy

For the Spacy package, model files for deps, ner, and pos throw an invalid load key or EOF error when I try to load them using pickle.

I have executed the code on windows and linux systems. I don't think it is a binary mode transfer issue. I have checked it in detail. I am not able to figure out the issue. Most likely the file is corrupt but I am not sure. Is there a way it can be fixed using the hex editor?

Any help is highly appreciated. It will be great if someone can explain pickling in a bit detail.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The English() object in Spacy is not pickable. See issue [#125](https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/issues/125)